# bash: cat + grep to produce several replicas merging two filles

Tags: bash, grep, cat

Using Linux bash command line, I need to merge two filles integrating several copies of the file1 inside the specified part of the file 2. The file 1 looks like:

```
ATOM      1  N   SER A   1      -2.390   4.343 -17.003  1.00 27.76           N1+
ATOM      2  CA  SER A   1      -2.066   5.647 -16.370  1.00 27.12           C  
ATOM      3  C   SER A   1      -2.394   5.608 -14.874  1.00 26.29           C  
ATOM      4  O   SER A   1      -3.014   4.627 -14.405  1.00 22.93           O  
ATOM      5  CB  SER A   1      -2.771   6.798 -17.057  1.00 28.10           C  
ATOM      6  OG  SER A   1      -2.538   8.023 -16.373  1.00 32.02           O  
ATOM      7  N   GLY A   2      -1.982   6.655 -14.162  1.00 25.31           N  
ATOM      8  CA  GLY A   2      -2.172   6.779 -12.716  1.00 24.93           C  
ATOM      9  C   GLY A   2      -0.888   6.336 -12.067  1.00 23.66           C  
ATOM     10  O   GLY A   2      -0.168   5.459 -12.608  1.00 27.42           O  
ATOM     11  N   PHE A   3      -0.636   6.866 -10.900  1.00 22.07           N  
ATOM     12  CA  PHE A   3       0.622   6.595 -10.191  1.00 21.70           C  
ATOM     13  C   PHE A   3       0.279   6.570  -8.716  1.00 20.39           C  
ATOM     14  O   PHE A   3      -0.265   7.544  -8.167  1.00 23.83           O
```

the file 2 is a multi-block, where separate parts are defined by model1,model 2, model N and separated by ENDMDL:

```
MODEL 1
REMARK VINA RESULT:    -7.828      0.000      0.000
REMARK INTER + INTRA:         -13.769
REMARK INTER:                 -10.110
REMARK INTRA:                  -3.659
REMARK UNBOUND:                -3.196
ENDMDL
MODEL 2
REMARK VINA RESULT:    -7.828      0.000      0.000
REMARK INTER + INTRA:         -13.769
REMARK INTER:                 -10.110
REMARK INTRA:                  -3.659
REMARK UNBOUND:                -3.196
ENDMDL
MODEL 3
REMARK VINA RESULT:    -7.828      0.000      0.000
REMARK INTER + INTRA:         -13.769
REMARK INTER:                 -10.110
REMARK INTRA:                  -3.659
REMARK UNBOUND:                -3.196
ENDMDL
```

I need to copy several times all the containt of the file 1 into the file 2 just before the separator `ENDMDL` (in the second file), thus  integrating several coppies of the file 1 into the file 2. Here is the example of expected output:

```
MODEL 1
REMARK VINA RESULT:    -7.828      0.000      0.000
REMARK INTER + INTRA:         -13.769
REMARK INTER:                 -10.110
REMARK INTRA:                  -3.659
REMARK UNBOUND:                -3.196
ATOM      1  N   SER A   1      -2.390   4.343 -17.003  1.00 27.76           N1+
ATOM      2  CA  SER A   1      -2.066   5.647 -16.370  1.00 27.12           C  
ATOM      3  C   SER A   1      -2.394   5.608 -14.874  1.00 26.29           C  
ATOM      4  O   SER A   1      -3.014   4.627 -14.405  1.00 22.93           O  
ATOM      5  CB  SER A   1      -2.771   6.798 -17.057  1.00 28.10           C  
ATOM      6  OG  SER A   1      -2.538   8.023 -16.373  1.00 32.02           O  
ATOM      7  N   GLY A   2      -1.982   6.655 -14.162  1.00 25.31           N  
ATOM      8  CA  GLY A   2      -2.172   6.779 -12.716  1.00 24.93           C  
ATOM      9  C   GLY A   2      -0.888   6.336 -12.067  1.00 23.66           C  
ATOM     10  O   GLY A   2      -0.168   5.459 -12.608  1.00 27.42           O  
ATOM     11  N   PHE A   3      -0.636   6.866 -10.900  1.00 22.07           N  
ATOM     12  CA  PHE A   3       0.622   6.595 -10.191  1.00 21.70           C  
ATOM     13  C   PHE A   3       0.279   6.570  -8.716  1.00 20.39           C  
ATOM     14  O   PHE A   3      -0.265   7.544  -8.167  1.00 23.83           O 
ENDMDL
MODEL 2
REMARK VINA RESULT:    -7.828      0.000      0.000
REMARK INTER + INTRA:         -13.769
REMARK INTER:                 -10.110
REMARK INTRA:                  -3.659
REMARK UNBOUND:                -3.196
ATOM      1  N   SER A   1      -2.390   4.343 -17.003  1.00 27.76           N1+
ATOM      2  CA  SER A   1      -2.066   5.647 -16.370  1.00 27.12           C  
ATOM      3  C   SER A   1      -2.394   5.608 -14.874  1.00 26.29           C  
ATOM      4  O   SER A   1      -3.014   4.627 -14.405  1.00 22.93           O  
ATOM      5  CB  SER A   1      -2.771   6.798 -17.057  1.00 28.10           C  
ATOM      6  OG  SER A   1      -2.538   8.023 -16.373  1.00 32.02           O  
ATOM      7  N   GLY A   2      -1.982   6.655 -14.162  1.00 25.31           N  
ATOM      8  CA  GLY A   2      -2.172   6.779 -12.716  1.00 24.93           C  
ATOM      9  C   GLY A   2      -0.888   6.336 -12.067  1.00 23.66           C  
ATOM     10  O   GLY A   2      -0.168   5.459 -12.608  1.00 27.42           O  
ATOM     11  N   PHE A   3      -0.636   6.866 -10.900  1.00 22.07           N  
ATOM     12  CA  PHE A   3       0.622   6.595 -10.191  1.00 21.70           C  
ATOM     13  C   PHE A   3       0.279   6.570  -8.716  1.00 20.39           C  
ATOM     14  O   PHE A   3      -0.265   7.544  -8.167  1.00 23.83           O 
ENDMDL
MODEL 3
REMARK VINA RESULT:    -7.828      0.000      0.000
REMARK INTER + INTRA:         -13.769
REMARK INTER:                 -10.110
REMARK INTRA:                  -3.659
REMARK UNBOUND:                -3.196
ATOM      1  N   SER A   1      -2.390   4.343 -17.003  1.00 27.76           N1+
ATOM      2  CA  SER A   1      -2.066   5.647 -16.370  1.00 27.12           C  
ATOM      3  C   SER A   1      -2.394   5.608 -14.874  1.00 26.29           C  
ATOM      4  O   SER A   1      -3.014   4.627 -14.405  1.00 22.93           O  
ATOM      5  CB  SER A   1      -2.771   6.798 -17.057  1.00 28.10           C  
ATOM      6  OG  SER A   1      -2.538   8.023 -16.373  1.00 32.02           O  
ATOM      7  N   GLY A   2      -1.982   6.655 -14.162  1.00 25.31           N  
ATOM      8  CA  GLY A   2      -2.172   6.779 -12.716  1.00 24.93           C  
ATOM      9  C   GLY A   2      -0.888   6.336 -12.067  1.00 23.66           C  
ATOM     10  O   GLY A   2      -0.168   5.459 -12.608  1.00 27.42           O  
ATOM     11  N   PHE A   3      -0.636   6.866 -10.900  1.00 22.07           N  
ATOM     12  CA  PHE A   3       0.622   6.595 -10.191  1.00 21.70           C  
ATOM     13  C   PHE A   3       0.279   6.570  -8.716  1.00 20.39           C  
ATOM     14  O   PHE A   3      -0.265   7.544  -8.167  1.00 23.83           O 
ENDMDL
```

I have tried to use cat BUT it just fused the both files together without the required replication of the first file:

```
cat file1.pdb file2.pdb > together.pdb
```

Need I pipe this to some expression of grep in order to replicate the file1  in the positions before the  ENDMDL of the file 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an awk solution that doesn't call unsafe `system` or `getline`:

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR {s = s $0 ORS; next} $0 == "ENDMDL" {$0 = s $0} 1' file1 file2
```

If you want to pass shell variable names then use:

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR {s = s $0 ORS; next}
$0 == "ENDMDL" {$0 = s $0} 1' "$file1" "$file2"
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `awk '...'  file2 file1` ?

Comment: Why do you say that it's unsafe to use `getline` in this case?

Comment: @Fravadona: Please [read this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139555/is-getline-in-awk-command-safe-to-use)

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`.

```
awk '/^ENDMDL$/ {system("cat file1.pdb");}; {print}' file2.pdb
```

Each line from `file2` is written to standard output, but when the line matches `ENDMDL`, the entire contents of `file1` are output first.

Some alternatives:

1. Replace `/^ENDMDL$/` with `$0 == "ENDMDL"`
2. Replace `{print}` with `1`. (With no explicit pattern, the action is performed. With no explicit action, the current line is printed.)

Comment: thank you! just one question how I can use bash variable inside this script assuming that I am running it inside of my bash script to provide the file1 and file2 as the shell variables. For example the following expressio with 'cat ${file1}' does not work:  awk '/^ENDMDL$/ {system('cat ${file1}');}; {print}' ${file2}

Comment: This might end up slower than the bash version... awk has its strong points as well as its weak points...

Comment: Only if `file1` is huge, and you can always read `file1` into memory in a `BEGIN` block if that's the case to avoid repeated re-reading. Reading line-by-line in `bash` is much slower than in `awk`.

Comment: The `read` builtin reads character-by-character until it finds a newline, rather than reading larger blocks and searching for a newline. It doesn't buffer anything so that it doesn't overconsume from standard input. Given something like `{ read header; cat > no header; } < file`, `noheader` is *guaranteed* to get everything except the first line of `file`; `read` will consume no more than is necessary to find the first linefeed.

Comment: well what I looking for is like: awk -v file1='${full_path}/file1.pdb' '/^ENDMDL$/ {system("cat file1");}; {print}' SarsCov2_06I_rep1.pdb >> test.pdb. but it does not work! I need to assosiate file1 variable of AWK with the path defined in bash script

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straight-forward awk solution:

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = RS = "\a"
        getline contents < ARGV[2]
        close(ARGV[2])
        ARGV[2] = ""
        RS = "\n"
    }
    /^ENDMDL$/ { printf "%s", contents }
    { print }
' file1 file2
```

The script slurps the file content (the one to be inserted) into a variable then prints it each time `ENDMDL` appears. I'm using the `BELL` character as `FS` and `RS` because you won't encounter it in a PDB file.